# dataframe cell compare string contains "="

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dataframes = pd.read_excel('file.csv')
dfColumn = dataframes[dataframes['Condition'] == "var.Var_type == "stringValue""]
```

Value in the field `condition` would be a STRING `var.Var_type == "stringValue"` var.var_type is not an actual variable in the code

I tried to find an equivalent to template literals but no luck in this context.

Comment: It's unclear without sample data. Do you mean `'"var.Var_type == "stringValue"'`? Can you provide a sample of the column you're trying to filter and the result you're looking to obtain?

Comment: @HenryEcker hope this gives you a clearer idea

Comment: So `dataframes[dataframes['Condition'] == 'var.Var_type == "stringValue"']`?

Comment: @HenryEcker exactly!